# VisualBrush (linked to VLC) doesn't change on TabControl selection change

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, vlc, visualbrush

I am having a weird experience with a combination of visual brush (linked to a VLC player through VLC.DotNet) and a tab control. I have created a custom control using the VLC player to watch an RTSP stream and have multiple of these controls in a given window.

The problem is that if I put all the controls in a list view they all display properly.  But if I put them in a tab control then it always shows the stream of the first-selected tab item, not matter what tab I'm currently on.  Everything else in the control (label, etc.) changes properly, but not the part drawn by the visual brush.

The view for my control is defined as:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myApp.View.CameraMonitorView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:Wpf="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <Grid Margin="3">
            <Grid.Background>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Image Source="{Binding VideoSource, ElementName=vlcControl}"/>
                        <!--<Image Source="{Binding Image}" /> -->
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Wpf:VlcControl x:Name="vlcControl" Margin="3"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind for the view starts playing the RTSP, but I don't think that code will help with this problem.

Meanwhile the ViewModel (stripped down for ease of viewing) is just:

```
class CameraMonitorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public CameraMonitorViewModel(string name, string image)
    {
        Name = name;
        Image = image;
    }

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a data template defined as:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CameraMonitorViewModel}">
    <v:CameraMonitorView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The full window view model has an ObservableCollection called Monitors and the view displays:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Monitors}" SelectedIndex="0" Height="300">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monitors}" Height="300" />
```

The ListView properly shows different images from each camera.  The tab item will always show the same camera, but the control's label item changes when I clicked different tabs.  Moreover, if I replace the databinding to the VLC control's image to the commented out static image object (whose source is set by way of the view model) then the image will properly change when I click different tabs.

I'm really confused and would appreciate any help that could be provided.

Comment: try removing 'SelectedIndex="0"'

Comment: @h.alex No luck.  Removing that line means none of the tabs are selected initially.  Once I select one, that camera's view gets 'stuck' as the only view that will show up.

Comment: Oh geez. I start the VLC control playing once its parent user control is loaded. And I just checked and only one control ever gets loaded from the tab control (and only after I click a tab if I don't have a selected index).  So I completely missed the issue.  Thank h.alex for helping me find this ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, as I noted in the comment to the question the problem was that I was starting the stream playing based on the Loaded event for the control. But it seems like it doesn't get fired after the second tab, probably because of what Rachel mentions here: [Loaded event doesn't fire for the 4th TabControl tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364656/loaded-event-doesnt-fire-for-the-4th-tabcontrol-tab) (being that it reuses the template rather than loading multiple ones).

Comment: you can ad an IsSelected property to your view model, remove the SelectedIndex = 0, and instead use SelectedItem = {Binding SelectedMonitor}, then add a SelectedMonitor property to your Master view model (one which has the Monitors property) and in the setter of the SelectedMonitor set the IsSelected of the selected monitor, and add the code to starting it to the IsSelected property setter instead of the Loaded event.

Comment: @h.alex So the only problem with that is that the code to play a stream actually requires the VLC control, which the ViewModel doesn't have access to (MVVM and all that).  And I'd also like to have all the streams running simultaneously (they don't soak that much bandwidth relatively speaking and the startup time is a bit excessive).  I honestly WANT multiple VLC controls which the tabcontrol apparently doesn't want to give me.  So I'll probably have to find a solution involving something other than a tabcontrol.

Comment: Oh. I see. Please look into [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization). It should help with getting multiple VLC controls from the TabControl. Other than that, this is a case when I personally would say it's ok to get the instance of a control into your VM. Use the load event of your VLC control, it's DataContext should be your VM, and pass this to the VM. If you want :)

Comment: @h.alex Thank you. I'd found that codeproject, but it's nice to have confirmation about that and also about the getting access to the control in the VM (I have another similar situation where I did what you described and was feeling a bit dirty).  Thanks and best of luck!

Comment: I use that codeproject in a production app, it works great. No problem, cheers!